# jQuery.ajaxでJSONがnullの場合の処理

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

jsonファイルの読み込みの際にnullが帰ってきた場合のみ表示させないようにしたいのですが、なかなかうまくできません。

以下コードになります。

time.json

```
{
　"fromTokyo" : {"air" : "1 hour 30 min", "train" : null, "bus" : null},
　"fromOsaka" : {"air" : "1 hour 45 min", "train" : null, "bus" : null},
　"fromFukuoka" : {"air" : "2 hour 10 min", "train" : null, "bus" : null}}
```

index.html

```
$(function() {
        $('#hoge').click(function(){
            $.ajax( {
                url: 'time.json',
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function( data ) {
                    var message = fromTokyo(data) + '</br>';
                    message = message + fromOsaka(data) + '</br>';
                    message = message + fromFukuoka(data);
                    $( '#fuga' ).html( message );
                },
                error: function( data ) {
                    $( '#fuga' ).html( '<font color="red">something went wrong.</font>' );
                }
            });
        }
        );
    });
　　　function fromTokyo(json) {
        var tokyo = "<b>From Tokyo</b>" + '</br>';
            tokyo = tokyo + 'Airplane : ' + json.fromTokyo.air + '</br>';
            tokyo = tokyo + 'Train : ' + json.fromTokyo.train + '</br>';
            tokyo = tokyo + 'Bus : ' + json.fromTokyo.bus + '</br>';
        return tokyo;
    }// 以下fromOsaka,fromFukuoka同じ関数
```

出力結果

From Tokyo
Airplane : 1 hour 30 min
Train : null
Bus : null

From Osaka
Airplane : 1 hour 45 min
Train : null
Bus : null

From Fukuoka 
Airplane : 2 hour 10 min
Train : null
Bus : null

ここでnullを持つデータは吐き出さずに、

From Tokyo
Airplane : 1 hour 30 min

From Osaka
Airplane : 1 hour 45 min

From Fukuoka 
Airplane : 2 hour 10 min

のようにしたいです。

ご教授宜しくお願いいたします。

＊追記＊
さらに発展させてみたく追記させていただきます。

日本地図をクリックして各都道府県の`attr`とマッチするデータを取得する事は可能でしょうか？
例えば`<p class="hokkaido" title="hokkaido">北海道</p>`をクリックして北海道へのアクセス時間のデータを以下のjsonから取得する形になります。

```
{
"hokkaido" : {
    "Tokyo" : {"air" : "1 hour 30 min", "train" : null, "bus" : null},
    "Osaka" : {"air" : "1 hour 45 min", "train" : null, "bus" : null},
    "Fukuoka" : {"air" : "2 hour 10 min", "train" : null, "bus" : null}
},
"aomori" : {
    "Tokyo" : {"air" : "1 hour 20 min", "train" : "3 hour 20 min", "bus" : null},
    "Osaka" : {"air" : null, "train" : null, "bus" : null},
    "Fukuoka" : {"air" : null, "train" : null, "bus" : null}
},
"iwate" : {
    "Tokyo" : {"air" : null, "train" : "2 hour 20 min", "bus" : "7 hour 25 min"},
    "Osaka" : {"air" : null, "train" : null, "bus" : null},
    "Fukuoka" : {"air" : null, "train" : null, "bus" : null}
},
"miyagi" : {
    "Tokyo" : {"air" : null, "train" : "1 hour 36 min", "bus" : "5 hour 27 min"},
    "Osaka" : {"air" : null, "train" : null, "bus" : null},
    "Fukuoka" : {"air" : null, "train" : null, "bus" : null}
} }
```

Comment: 追記分の質問は元の質問と内容が異なりますので、新しい質問に分けた方が良いですよ。

Answer (score 1):

これでできます。
必要に応じて`undefined`も非表示の条件に入れてください。

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var data = {
      "fromTokyo" : {"air" : "1 hour 30 min", "train" : null, "bus" : null},
      "fromOsaka" : {"air" : "1 hour 45 min", "train" : null, "bus" : null},
      "fromFukuoka" : {"air" : "2 hour 10 min", "train" : null, "bus" : null}
    }

    function fromTokyo(json) {
      var tokyo = "<b>From Tokyo</b>" + '<br />';
      if(json.fromTokyo.air != null){
        tokyo += 'Airplane : ' + json.fromTokyo.air + '<br />';
      }
      if(json.fromTokyo.train != null){
        tokyo += 'Train : ' + json.fromTokyo.train + '<br />';
      }
      if(json.fromTokyo.bus != null){
        tokyo += 'Bus : ' + json.fromTokyo.bus + '<br />';
      }
      return tokyo;
    }

    $('div').html( fromTokyo(data) );

  });
</script>

<div></div>
```

余談ですが･･･
`"fromTokyo", "fromOsaka", "fromFukuoka"`と同じデータ構造を持っているなら、関数に渡すときにこう渡せばメソッドは一つで済みます。
メソッド名`fromXXX`はセンスないので何か別の名前にした方がいいですね。。

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var data = {
      "fromTokyo" : {"air" : "1 hour 30 min", "train" : null, "bus" : null},
      "fromOsaka" : {"air" : "1 hour 45 min", "train" : null, "bus" : null},
      "fromFukuoka" : {"air" : "2 hour 10 min", "train" : null, "bus" : null}
    }

    function fromXXX(location) {
      var output = "";
      if(location.air != null){
        output += 'Airplane : ' + location.air + '<br />';
      }
      if(location.train != null){
        output += 'Train : ' + location.train + '<br />';
      }
      if(location.bus != null){
        output += 'Bus : ' + location.bus + '<br />';
      }
      return output;
    }

    var message = "";
    message += "<b>From Tokyo</b>" + '<br />';
    message += fromXXX(data.fromTokyo);
    message += "<b>From Osaka</b>" + '<br />';
    message += fromXXX(data.fromOsaka);
    message += "<b>From Fukuoka</b>" + '<br />';
    message += fromXXX(data.fromFukuoka);

    $('div').html( message );

  });
</script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: 有難うございました。上記のコードで期待通りの結果が出力されました。
また、同じデータ構造の際の処理も大変勉強になりました。

Answer (score 0):

fromTokyoで

```
if(json.fromTokyo.train)
{
    tokyo += 'Train :' + json.fromTokyo.train + '<br />';
}
```

のように分岐してやる必要があるかと。

### 追記部分に関して

JSONが`data`に取得済みとしたら`data.hokkaido`というようなデータにアクセスしたいのですよね。
これは`data['hokkaido']`という書き方が出来ますので、jqueryを使って

```
$('p').click(function(){
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    var prefData = data[title];
    // 既存の表示処理
});
```

のように共通処理を記述できます。実際には`$('p')`だけでは範囲が広いので、各都道府県の`p`に共通のクラス(たとえば`prefecture`)を指定して`$('p.prefecture')`と変え、`title`属性も表示に影響するため`data-title`等に変更したほうが良いと思います。

Comment: ご回答いただきまして有難うございました。
最後のif(tokyo)の部分は私の間違いでしたので修正させていただきました。

教えていただきましたコードでうまくいきましたが、
他のケースもあり、json.fromTokyo.trainがnullではなくなった場合は通常出力できるようにしたい場合はどうなるでしょうか？

質問ばかりで恐縮ですが宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: @kphex すみませんがコメントの意図がちょっとわかりません。回答のコードで`json.fromTokyo.train`が`null`の場合とそうではない場合に対応しているつもりですがどのようなケースを想定していますか？

Comment: 私の説明不足で申し訳ありません。意図としてはさらに上の階層にて条件をつけるつもりでして、例えば北海道を選択した場合の東京、大阪、福岡からの時間、長野を選択した場合の東京、大阪、福岡からの時間、、、といった具合に常に値がnullとは限らないケースを想定しておりました。